# Center div vertically inside navigation with non-default body font

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I have a simple navigation with simple texts, but my list item is a div. I would like to center the div vertically. When I started the project everything looked great until I changed the body's font. I don't understand how does it affect the div, because the div doesn't have text inside. I always deal with problems like this, even though I read many articles about centering.

I inserted the code here, and I also created a jsfiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/0vwhjnnw/1/

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800italic,800,700italic,700,600italic,600,400italic,300italic,300&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext);

body {
 font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

ul { 
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    line-height:80px;
}

li { 
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px;
    background:#ccc;
    float:left;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

a {
    padding:0 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.arrow {
    width:30px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href=""><span class="item">Menu 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="item">Menu 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="item">Menu 3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="item">Menu 4</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

What do you think, how can I center the blue div vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that would help you to align dive vertically center

https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Comment: I can align it if the font is browser's default.

Comment: The problem is right: 0 in ul style not with font. Pls refer this http://jsfiddle.net/0vwhjnnw/4/

Comment: It's not centered and I need the right:0; property.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correct you can add this to your css

```
    li {
    position: relative;
}

.position-absolute-xy-axis {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

and add the position-absolute-xy-axis class in your html

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href=""><span class="item">Menu 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href=""><span class="item">Menu 2</span></a></li>
<li><a href=""><span class="item">Menu 3</span></a></li>
<li><a href=""><span class="item">Menu 4</span></a></li>
<li><a href=""><span class="arrow position-absolute-xy-axis"></span></a></li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/twk0z2qh/

Personally i would play around with flexbox
https://jsfiddle.net/qLumzy65/1/

Comment: Honestly I'm interested about this behavior. Why is the font affects the centering of an empty div?

Comment: Not sure i understand the question :) But did the solution work for you?